# ManyToMany in Django Admin as Muti Select CheckBox

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i'm using python 3.9 with django 4.1.

I have list of apartments and list of their commodities, each apartment can have zero or more commodities.

the modes are created as such:

```
class Commodities(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('English Name'), unique=True, blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    name_he = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Hebrew Name'), unique=True, blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    name_fr = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('French Name'), unique=True, blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(name_en__isnull=False) | Q(name_he__isnull=False) | Q(name_fr__isnull=False),
                name='not_all_null_commodities'
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())


class Apartment(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, verbose_name=_('Apartment Address'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    floor = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Floor'), null=True, blank=True)
    apartment = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Apartment'), null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address.__str__() + \
               (' ' + _('Entrance') + ' ' + self.address.entrance if self.address.entrance else '') + \
               (' ' + _('Floor') + ' ' + str(self.floor) if self.floor else '') + \
               (' ' + _('Apartment') + ' ' + self.apartment if self.apartment else '')


class ApartmentCommodities(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Apartment'))
    commodity = models.ForeignKey(Commodities, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.apartment.__str__() + ' - ' + getattr(self.commodity, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())
```

I want in the admin page, when I add or modify an apartment, to see the commodities as multi-checkbox instead of selecting adding and removing each commodity line by line.

I googled a lot.. and I read about filter_horizontal at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal

and I tried to give it a go

so I create a `forms.py` with this code:

```
class CommoditiesModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Commodities
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['commodities'].queryset = Commodities
```

and then I created `admin.ModelAdmin` for the apartments

```
class ApartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CommoditiesModelForm
    list_display = ('get_country', 'get_city', 'get_street', 'get_number', 'get_entrance', 'apartment', 'floor')
    #inlines = [ApartmentCommoditiesInline]
    filter_horizontal = ('commodities',)
```

but this returns the error:

```
<class 'goods.admin.ApartmentAdmin'>: (admin.E019) The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' refers to 'commodities', which is not a field of 'goods.Apartment'.
```

i read somewhere that it's supposed to be enough to add `formfiled_override` to create this effect like this:

```
 class ApartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
```

but it didn't change anything.

so how can I properly resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so django can automate stuff behind the scenes more than i knew :)

first I create a many-to-many relationship from the apartments model to the commodities module:

```
class Apartment(models.Model):
...
    commodities = models.ManyToManyField(Commodities)
...
```

I remove the `CommoditiesModelForm` that I tried to work with, also removed `ApartmentCommodities` model since that `models.ManyToManyField` is creating something like for me behind the scenes, i also don't need an inline `ApartmentCommoditiesInline` to the Admin Module.

now when the apartment model do have a many-to-many relationship i can just use `formfield_overrides` on it:

```
class ApartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
```

and that's it :)